# want to make filter product for ecommerce website AspNet Core

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor-pages

Help, want to make filter product with more than one parameter (Category) for ecommerce website Asp.Net Core and razor pages
not with textbox i can do it i need it with checkbox or dropdown multiable
so please help i finished most of the website, i tried but i can't.
and i maked that action for search with 3 textboxes

```
    `[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Search(string Id, string Id2, string Id3)
    {
        var Result = from Res in _context.ItEntity.Include(i => i.CaRelation)
                     .Include(i => i.FaRelation)
                     .Include(i => i.ITImages)
                     select Res;
        //var Result = _context.ItEntity.AsQueryable();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
        {
            Result = Result.Where(x => x.ITName.Contains(Id));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id2))
        {
            Result = Result.Where(x => x.FaRelation.FaName == Id2);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id3))
        {
            Result = Result.Where(x => x.CaRelation.CaName == Id3);
        }
        return PartialView("_Search", await Result.ToListAsync());
    }
```

`

Comment: You'll need to be far more clear with what you're trying to achieve. And you'll also need to clearly describe what you've tried in order to solve the problem you're having. Otherwise, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks david for your advice, i achieved it, i'm trying to get more experience and to be more professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working demo about how to use `DropdownList` to filter the result together with displaying by `partial view` like below:

*Model:*

```
public class ItEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ITName { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public CaRelation CaRelation { get; set; }
    public FaRelation FaRelation { get; set; }
    public ITImages ITImages { get; set; }
}
public class CaRelation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CaName { get; set; }
}
public class FaRelation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FaName { get; set; }
}
public class ITImages
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImName { get; set; }
}
```

*Index.cshtml:*

```
@model IEnumerable<ItEntity>
<form method="get" asp-action="Search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">ITName</label>
        <select id="Id" asp-items="ViewBag.IT"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">FaName</label>
        <select id="Id2" asp-items="ViewBag.FaName"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">CaName</label>
        <select id="Id3" asp-items="ViewBag.CaName"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="data"></div>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var filters = {
            Id: null,
            Id2: null,
            Id3: null
            };
            GetData(filters);
        });
        $('#btnSearch').on('click', function (e) {
            var filters = {
                Id: $('#Id').val(),
                Id2: $('#Id2').val(),
                Id3: $('#Id3').val()
            };
            GetData(filters);
        });
        function GetData(filters) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Tests/Search',
                type: 'Get',
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                dataType: "html",
                data : filters
                })
                .done(function (result) {
                $('#data').html(result);
                }).fail(function (xhr) {
                console.log('error : ' + xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.statusText + ' - ' + xhr.responseText);
                });

        }
    </script>
}
```

*_Search.cshtml:*

Note:Be sure the partial view has been located in the correct folder,refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1#partial-view-discovery).

```
@model IEnumerable<ItEntity>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FaRelation.FaName)               
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CaRelation.CaName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Details)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FaRelation.FaName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CaRelation.CaName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Details)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*Controller:*

```
public class TestsController : Controller
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _context;

    public TestsController(YourDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    // GET: Tests
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {

        ViewBag.IT = new SelectList(_context.ItEntity.Select(i => i.ITName).ToList());
        ViewBag.FaName = new SelectList(_context.FaRelation.Select(i => i.FaName).ToList());
        ViewBag.CaName = new SelectList(_context.CaRelation.Select(i => i.CaName).ToList());
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Search(string Id, string Id2, string Id3)
    {
        var Result = from Res in _context.ItEntity.Include(i => i.CaRelation)
                     .Include(i => i.FaRelation)
                     .Include(i => i.ITImages)
                     select Res;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
        {
            Result = Result.Where(x => x.ITName.Contains(Id));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id2))
        {
            Result = Result.Where(x => x.FaRelation.FaName == Id2);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id3))
        {
            Result = Result.Where(x => x.CaRelation.CaName == Id3);
        }
        return PartialView("_Search", await Result.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

*Result:*
[image]

Comment: OMG thanks rena for your effort and helping me, i was thinking that i will never get any hand to help me, but i'm trying to pass multiple parameter from category dropdown to filter depending on it, 2 or 3 category and getting the products that has that 2 or 3 category

Comment: Did you mean you want one selectlist and you could multiple choose the item?

Comment: I maked it with checkboxes i returned the categories in viewbag and passing list of int in action then returning all the items with condition where (listofint.contains(x.categoryId)) || listofint.count == 0)

Comment: Then i returned the variable with paginglist and returning the viewmodel

Comment: If you have an advice for Registration Confirmation Email and Forget Password Send Email with link, I'm going to make the with identity they aren't working need some modifications

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61014918/how-can-i-fix-email-confirmation-in-core-dosent-work