# SendGrid Email - RegisterConfirmation - email not receive

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a problem with register confirmation. I am working with ASP.NET CORE 3.1 and i am building my app with tutorials from MS [Tutorial Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#prevent-login-at-registration)

I want to after registration new user receive an email to confirmation register. On below is my code:

EMailSender.cs

```
    public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; } //set only via Secret Manager

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
    }

    public Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)
    {
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var msg = new SendGridMessage()
        {
            From = new EmailAddress("kris202kris@gmail.com", Options.SendGridUser),
            Subject = subject,
            PlainTextContent = message,
            HtmlContent = message
        };
        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));

        // Disable click tracking.
        // See https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html
        msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);

        var response = client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        
        //return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        return response;
    }
}
```

AuthMessageSenderOptions.cs

```
    public class AuthMessageSenderOptions
{
    public string SendGridUser { get; set; }
    public string SendGridKey { get; set; }
}
```

Startup.cs (part)

```
            // Email sending settings
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(_config);
```

RegisterConfirmation.cshtml.cs

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
public class RegisterConfirmationModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IEmailSender _sender;

    public RegisterConfirmationModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IEmailSender sender)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _sender = sender;
    }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public bool DisplayConfirmAccountLink { get; set; }

    public string EmailConfirmationUrl { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string email, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (email == null)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }

        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with email '{email}'.");
        }

        Email = email;

        await _sender.SendEmailAsync(email, "Register Confirmation", "Html message");

        return Page();
    }
}
```

I have also secrets.json:

```
{"SendGridUser" : "MyUserName", "SendGridKey" : "SG.5r.......WuU" }
```

Do you have any ideas my friends?

Comment: You're not awaiting methods. e.g you should have  return await Execute(...) and var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

Comment: @Greg

public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
        {
            return await Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
        }
 But now i get an error _italic_CS1997 C# Since is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return?_italic_

Comment: Furthermore I am not sure it is good idea because i have await method here:
 await _sender.SendEmailAsync(email, "Register Confirmation", "Html message"); So my program still waiting for execute (if I understand correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Task` Functions to `Async Task`. (Execute and SendEmailAsync)

Then call all the Async Task functions with `return await Execute(...)` and `return await client.SendEmailAsync(msg)`

Answer (score 0):

Sendgrid does not allow you to use GMAIL or YAHOO as the sender. Refer to the answer to your problem [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61014918/how-can-i-fix-email-confirmation-in-net-core-it-doesnt-work). In your code, you are using `"kris202kris@gmail.com"`. I'm guessing that is your problem.