# ASP .Net Identity Confirm email not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to make registration and login system, and everything works fine.I tried also to make Confirm Email option that will confirm your email when you try to sign up but parameters : SendGridKey and SendGridUser are allways null. Where should I insert the API key, and I can't get why SendGrid User are alway null.

This is what I trued :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new AppUtent { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email , FirstName = Input.Nome, LastName= Input.Cognome};
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

         
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXfMA.png)

I used c# identity.

Any suggestion how to fix this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: from where you get the `SendGridKey` ? Its probably null because you start 2 new threads, and you do not keep that parameters to pass to that threads - threads that you not need by the way on a web application call...

Comment: First, please check the Startup.cs file, make sure you have already registered the Email Sender service. You can refer the following articles: [Account confirmation and password recovery in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) and [Require Confirmed Email in ASP.NET Core](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1272172/). Besides, according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61014918/), it seems that when send email use Sendgrid, you should use your own mail domain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how far you are with your project. But SendGridKey and SendGridUser are both things needed to send emails using SendGrid email service.

My guess is your following this guide: [Account confirmation and password recovery in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

So first you need to sign up here: [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/)

In the first link guide they talk about creating a class:

```
public class AuthMessageSenderOptions
{
    public string SendGridUser { get; set; }
    public string SendGridKey { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the console use the Dotnet secret tool to add SendGridUser and SendGridKey like so:

```
dotnet user-secrets set SendGridUser <Your Sendgrid User>
dotnet user-secrets set SendGridKey <Your Sendgrid key>
```

Then in Startup.cs of your project add:

```
services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
```

If you have any problems, please read through the guide in link number 1. Seems like your 85% there. Just need to secure that SendGridUser and SendGridKey gets values.

------ HACK DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION ------

If you just want to test it out quick without console commands you could "cheat" and add class AuthMessageSenderOptions like so

```
public class AuthMessageSenderOptions
{
    public string SendGridUser { get; set; } = "<Replace with Sendgrid user>"
    public string SendGridKey { get; set; } = "<Replace with Sendgrid key>"
}
```

and add it as singleton in Startup.cs like so:

services.AddSingleton();

Then it will just have default values hardcoded instead of checking secret store. BUT DONT TAKE THIS IN PRODUCTION! :) Just so you can test stuff out.

Comment: Thanks, I have already done all this steaps. I can't find my Sendgrid user. It should be the email that I login?

Comment: SendGridUser and SendGridKey is valued, but when I control my mail, I can't find the email.

Comment: I would check spam folder. Check logs for exceptions, if something is setup wrong, like wrong user / key. Eg. Try sending 5 mails quick and check logs afterwards.

Maybe try setting up a "Test" ApiController that sends a mail, for easy access to check if you can get any email sent out.